# Convert each element in php array to separated parameter for function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Hie everyone am trying to pass the following array:

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
```

To the following function

```
function foo(){
   $numargs = func_num_args();
   $args = func_get_args();
   print_r($args);
}
```

What I want is to make each element in array to be separated element in $args

at the same time I don't to write the function and parameters like that way

```
foo($cars[0],$cars[1]);
```

Comment: `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer                                               I've already use call_user_func_array() but all elements of $cars array has become the first element of $args array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($array); $i++) {
 $c = $array[$i];
 foo($c);
}

?>
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding some more explanations

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely sure what it is you are asking but here would be a simple solution:
Change foo to:

```
function foo(){
   $args = func_get_args()[0];
}
```

$args will then contain the array of element you pass into foo() if you called it like this:

```
foo($cars);
```

In case you may be passing more than just the array parameter you would need to loop over the arguments and then could do something with each:

```
foo(){
   $args = func_get_args();
   while(!empty($args))
   {
      //do something with each argument. ie. print out it's value
      print_r(array_shift($args));
   }
}
```

Call it again by the same way: `foo($cars);`

It seems a little bit strange what you are trying to so though as I think you could just write you foo method as:

```
foo($array){
    foreach($array as $array_item)
    {
       // do something with each item ie. print out it's value
       print_r($array_item);
    }
}
```